# Rails: update id between two tables relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 4 tables:

```
A has many B
B belong_to A

C has many D
D belong_to C

A has_one C
B has one D
```

From:
edit, insert to B

```
row 1 
row 2
```

Model

```
def self.build_width_invoice(hash1, hash2)
    doc = Doc.new(hash1) # hash hash B_attributes
    doc.build_C(hash2)  # hash hash D_attributes
    doc
end
```

controller

```
obj = A.build_width_invoice(hash1, hash2)
obj.save

save to A, B
        C, D   ok
```

every id relationship have filled  but id_D int table B do not have value

Data B and D is the same

How can i  insert it?

Comment: Do you have `C belongs_to A` and `D belongs_to B` as well?

Comment: no C and A, D and B do not relate

Comment: That might be your problem. Every `has_one` relationship must have a counterpart. The same thing happens with `has_many`.

Comment: Do you want to talk:
 doc = A.new(hash)
 doc.b.each |item| 
    doc.b.build_d(item)
 end
 is this right?

Comment: You mentioned you have a `A has_one C` association. If that is the case, then you need to have `C belongs_to A` as well.

Comment: i can explain clearly: A: is invoice, B: invoice_item, C: Deal 
Deal has many transaction. one transaction has many D: line_item.

invoice has many invoice_item.
invoice has one deal.

deal has many transactions.
transactions has many line_item.

invoice_item has one line_item.

i want to know to to insert line_item_id to invoice_item_id.

It is really complex with me